What kind of general purpose vacuum pump gives me an oil-less high level vacuum?
Vacuuming non dry product made a mayonnaise from my 2 stages vacuum pump oil.

How comes this mayonnaise is so stable and turned up to be very hard
to break ?
What kind of common vacuum pump could give me the same
level of vacuum (let's say : better than 0.1Pa) without requiring
oil ?

